# Link to a custom page without a permalink?

Tags: permalinks, blog-page

I am working on a custom Wordpress theme, I have the index.php setup for the Home view, I'd like to create another page to list all the blog posts, I am familiar with the loop, I just want to know how to link to the new page properly. Here's what I am using

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/blogs.php">Blog Listing</a>
```

However when I get redirect to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/final/blogs.php` I get `atal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function the_title() in`, I am guessing it's interpreting the `blogs.php` on the face level and not passing the wordpress context. A little help is required.

Comment: Hello Sahil and welcome to WPSE.  You are correct.  WordPress is actually not running when you attempt to load a template file directly.  Let the CMS handle that.  From your question, it seems you want a static front page and a blog home page separately.  I would restore the index.php file to its original state and read this:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you to @jdm2112 for such a quick response. I was able to serve a custom page by creating a page from inside the Wordpress admin panel to get a permalink `wordpress.live/blogs`. After that I setup my `page.php` to loop through all the `posts` using the following code

```
<?php get_header();?>
        <?php $wpdb = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'post_status' => 'published',
            'posts_per_page' => -1));

            if($wpdb->have_posts()):
                while($wpdb->have_posts()):
                    $wpdb->the_post();?>
            <?php
            // This calls the blogs.php that has the custom layout for blog listing.
            get_template_part('blogs');
                // echo the_title();
                endwhile;
            endif;
            ?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

simply calling `the_title()` from blogs.php prints out the all the posts title.
Blogs.php

```
 the_title();
```